# Combining multiple lines of telnet into 1 batch file

Tags: batch-file, telnet

To perform a specific task I had to do the following commands

```
telnet 10.0.0.192 *hit enter
y (answer yes to whatever question comes up) *hit enter
DOMAIN\username (when prompted for username) *hit enter
password (when prompted for password) *hit enter
\\10.0.0.2\path\batchFile.bat (this is the batch file I'd like to run in the end) *hit neter
```

Is there a way I can combine all this data into 1 batch file (saving passwords into it is fine) so that I simply have to double click the batch file and it ends up executing `batchFile.bat` on the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

This is a scriptable telnet client that can be launched in a batch file. Google for it.

Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0
by Albert Yale

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to automate this entierly using a batch file. You can however use something like a VBS script to manage the session. Here's an example of such a script (called DoTelnet.vbs, for the sake of this example):

```
    Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    myShell.run "cmd"
    WScript.Sleep 100

    myShell.SendKeys"telnet 127.0.0.1"
    myShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
    WScript.Sleep 100

etc...
```

You could then call this from your batch file with:

```
cscript DoTelnet.vbs
```